# dependencies not met while installing digikam 4

Tags: dependencies, digikam

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

digikam: Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
         Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
         Depends: digikam-data (= 4:4.6.0-trusty~ppa1kde414) but 4:4.6.0-trusty~ppa1kde414 is
 to be installed
```

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy digikam libqtcore4 libqtgui4 digikam-data`